# "Out of memory" while parsing large (100 Mb) XML file using perl

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

I have an error "*Out of memory*" while parsing large (100 Mb) XML file

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $twig=XML::Twig->new();
my $data = XML::Twig->new
             ->parsefile("divisionhouserooms-v3.xml")
               ->simplify( keyattr => []);

my @good_division_numbers = qw( 30 31 32 35 38 );

foreach my $property ( @{ $data->{DivisionHouseRoom}}) {

    my $house_code = $property->{HouseCode};
    print $house_code, "\n";

    my $amount_of_bedrooms = 0;

    foreach my $division ( @{ $property->{Divisions}->{Division} } ) {

        next unless grep { $_ eq $division->{DivisionNumber} } @good_division_numbers;
        $amount_of_bedrooms += $division->{DivisionQuantity};
    }

    open my $fh, ">>", "Result.csv" or die $!;
    print $fh join("\t", $house_code, $amount_of_bedrooms), "\n";
    close $fh;
}
```

What i can do to fix this error issue?

Comment: For big XML files, you should rely on event oriented parsers, like SAX. I don't know perl, but do you know if there is something similar?

Comment: I do not know this module, but there on [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::Twig) they do mention how to handle small vs huge files, and what you have here is the version for "small". So perhaps you might adapt your code to the "huge" implementation.

Comment: @Rubens - see below excellent answers, but short version is "Indubitably, Perl has SAX parsers".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Handling large XML files that don't fit in memory is something that [`XML::Twig`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aTwig) [advertises](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aTwig#Processing_an_XML_document_chunk_by_chunk):

> One of the strengths of `XML::Twig` is that it let you work with files
>   that do not fit in memory (BTW storing an XML document in memory as a
>   tree is quite memory-expensive, the expansion factor being often
>   around 10).
>
> To do this you can define handlers, that will be called once a
>   specific element has been completely parsed. In these handlers you can
>   access the element and process it as you see fit (...)

---

The code posted in the question isn't making use of the strength of `XML::Twig` at all (using the `simplify` method doesn't make it much better than [`XML::Simple`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aSimple)).

What's missing from the code are the '`twig_handlers`' or '`twig_roots`', which essentially cause the parser to focus on relevant portions of the XML document memory-efficiently.

It's difficult to say without seeing the XML whether [processing the document chunk-by-chunk](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.38/Twig_pm.slow#Processing_an_XML_document_chunk_by_chunk) or [just selected parts](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.38/Twig_pm.slow#Processing_just_parts_of_an_XML_document) is the way to go, but either one should solve this issue.

So the code should look something like the following (chunk-by-chunk demo):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;
use List::Util 'sum';   # To make life easier
use Data::Dump 'dump';  # To see what's going on

my %bedrooms;           # Data structure to store the wanted info

my $xml = XML::Twig->new (
                          twig_roots => {
                                          DivisionHouseRoom => \&count_bedrooms,
                                        }
                         );

$xml->parsefile( 'divisionhouserooms-v3.xml');

sub count_bedrooms {

    my ( $twig, $element ) = @_;

    my @divParents = $element->children( 'Divisions' );
    my $id = $element->first_child_text( 'HouseCode' );

    for my $divParent ( @divParents ) {
        my @divisions = $divParent->children( 'Division' );
        my $total = sum map { $_->text } @divisions;
        $bedrooms{$id} = $total;
    }

    $element->purge;   # Free up memory
}

dump \%bedrooms;
```

Answer (score 8):

See [Processing an XML document chunk by chunk](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aTwig#Processing_an_XML_document_chunk_by_chunk) section of [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aTwig) documentation, it specifically discuss how to process document part by part, allowing for large XML file processing.